# How to figure out which class shap_values[0] and shap_values[1] belong to?

Tags: python, pandas, shap

From my understanding shap_values[0] and shap_values[1] are just array of probabilities and if shap_values[0] is p then shap_value[1] is 1-p. However, can anyone advise me how to verify which classes the shap_values[0] and shap_values[1] belong to.

I have two classes in my dataset but don't know which shap_value belong to which class.

For example consider I have classes - ERROR, NO_ERROR

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer - Hope it helps for beginners like me. https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1252#issuecomment-857469497

"You can verify this in scikit-learn models by looking at the model object's .classes_ attribute. This will contain an array of the model's classes, in order."